# how 2 specify TCP scaling since there is no field tht relates 2 TCP scaling in struct tcphdr/can I do "struct tcp_info *opt=tcph+sizeof(struct tcphdr)

Tags: c, tcp

I like to set the receive window TCP scaling factor.

But in tcphdr there is no field that relates to tcp scaling

This is my netinet/tcp.h `struct tcphdr`

```
struct tcphdr
  {
    __extension__ union
    {
      struct
      {
    uint16_t th_sport;  /* source port */
    uint16_t th_dport;  /* destination port */
    tcp_seq th_seq;     /* sequence number */
    tcp_seq th_ack;     /* acknowledgement number */
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    uint8_t th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
    uint8_t th_off:4;   /* data offset */
# endif
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    uint8_t th_off:4;   /* data offset */
    uint8_t th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
# endif
    uint8_t th_flags;
# define TH_FIN 0x01
# define TH_SYN 0x02
# define TH_RST 0x04
# define TH_PUSH    0x08
# define TH_ACK 0x10
# define TH_URG 0x20
    uint16_t th_win;    /* window */
    uint16_t th_sum;    /* checksum */
    uint16_t th_urp;    /* urgent pointer */
      };
      struct
      {
    uint16_t source;
    uint16_t dest;
    uint32_t seq;
    uint32_t ack_seq;
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    uint16_t res1:4;
    uint16_t doff:4;
    uint16_t fin:1;
    uint16_t syn:1;
    uint16_t rst:1;
    uint16_t psh:1;
    uint16_t ack:1;
    uint16_t urg:1;
    uint16_t res2:2;
# elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    uint16_t doff:4;
    uint16_t res1:4;
    uint16_t res2:2;
    uint16_t urg:1;
    uint16_t ack:1;
    uint16_t psh:1;
    uint16_t rst:1;
    uint16_t syn:1;
    uint16_t fin:1;
# else
#  error "Adjust your <bits/endian.h> defines"
# endif
    uint16_t window;
    uint16_t check;
    uint16_t urg_ptr;
      };
    };
};
```

So I like to know can i set TCP scaling factor if I have [pointer to `struct tcphdr`] to buffer that I will send. does anyone know this?

There is a `struct tcp_info` on my system can I use this to accoplish like tcp option for window scaling because this seems to be like window scaling options like  `uint8_t    tcpi_snd_wscale : 4, tcpi_rcv_wscale : 4;` so can I set these option some how, does anyone know

```
struct tcp_info
{
  uint8_t   tcpi_state;
  uint8_t   tcpi_ca_state;
  uint8_t   tcpi_retransmits;
  uint8_t   tcpi_probes;
  uint8_t   tcpi_backoff;
  uint8_t   tcpi_options;
  uint8_t   tcpi_snd_wscale : 4, tcpi_rcv_wscale : 4;

  uint32_t  tcpi_rto;
  uint32_t  tcpi_ato;
  uint32_t  tcpi_snd_mss;
  uint32_t  tcpi_rcv_mss;

  uint32_t  tcpi_unacked;
  uint32_t  tcpi_sacked;
  uint32_t  tcpi_lost;
  uint32_t  tcpi_retrans;
  uint32_t  tcpi_fackets;

  /* Times. */
  uint32_t  tcpi_last_data_sent;
  uint32_t  tcpi_last_ack_sent; /* Not remembered, sorry.  */
  uint32_t  tcpi_last_data_recv;
  uint32_t  tcpi_last_ack_recv;

  /* Metrics. */
  uint32_t  tcpi_pmtu;
  uint32_t  tcpi_rcv_ssthresh;
  uint32_t  tcpi_rtt;
  uint32_t  tcpi_rttvar;
  uint32_t  tcpi_snd_ssthresh;
  uint32_t  tcpi_snd_cwnd;
  uint32_t  tcpi_advmss;
  uint32_t  tcpi_reordering;

  uint32_t  tcpi_rcv_rtt;
  uint32_t  tcpi_rcv_space;

  uint32_t  tcpi_total_retrans;
};
```

Comment: rfc1323 has to be agreed by both sender and receiver. It can't just be set by one end.

Comment: @stark sender broadcasted window scaling I am the receiver now I need to broadcast it. How to do it